# what's a good form-checking library with conditional validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, validation

I had been using [jsvalidate](http://www.jsvalidate.com/), but it doesn't fit my requirement of conditional validation for what I want to do; I want to make a couple of fields required only if a select is previously marked as yes.

I have been looking into [mootools's formcheck](http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/), it seems a bit fancier and nicer than [jquery's validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), but I don't know if it would allow me to do a conditional validation. Which should I pick here to make my job easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used **[Ketchup](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/validation.html)**, another jQuery form validation plug-in. You can write your own validators with jQuery to use custom conditions.